# Cannot Save PPM File

Tags: c++, ppm

I'm working on a c++ project and I wanted to write a PPM file with some basic RGB colors for testing. When I run the programm, everything seems to work great with no error from the compiler, but when I can't find the image in the project directory when I search for it. 
I've never tried to output PPM File, I'm sure it's my error but I can't find where's my mistake. 
Here's my code :

```
    std::ostringstream header;
    header << "P6\n";
    header << width << ' ' << height << '\n';
    header << "255\n";
    std::ofstream file("test.ppm", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    file << header.str();
```

And into the x,y loop

```
for(size_t y=0; y<height..)
    for(size_t x=0; x<width..){
        unsigned char r, g, b;
        r = static_cast<unsigned char>(.1f * 255.0);
        g = static_cast<unsigned char>(.1f * 255.0);
        b = static_cast<unsigned char>(.1f * 255.0);
        file << r << g << b;
}

fileStream.flush();
fileStream.close();
```

Of course, it's just a test, I don't really care about the output's final color. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Why use the ostringstream for the header? Why not just write directly into the file `ofstream`?  Also, please post your actual code or at least a minimal reproduction case, since this is clearly not the code that's compiling fine.

Comment: Try adding some actual error checking.  You have no idea if the file was opened or if any of the writes were successful.  Since you're using a relative path the file will be wherever the working directory is if you run the program inside XCode.  It may not be the project directory.